# Changing the UID of files in /proc

Tags: users, su, proc, setuid

In a follow up to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id) about changing the `UID` of a user, it is recommended to change the ownership of **all files** on the system ([this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/16719/19760))

```
find / -uid 1000 -exec chown 5000 '{}' \+
```

where `1000` is the old `UID` and `5000` is the new one. I just listed all files (outside `/home/seb`) owned by `UID=1000` and found that most are in the `/proc` directory.

```
find / -uid 1000 \! -wholename '/home/seb/*'
```

Is it *save* or *necessary* to perform the suggested `UID` change? I'm not familiar with the purpose of these `/proc` files, but I assume they would be created as needed when I log in with the new user.

Note: There are also some files in `/dev` owned by `UID=1000`, but those are just the terminals open by the user (e.g. `/dev/pts/23`)

Comment: `/proc` is a virtual filesystem used for processes (remember UNIX philosophy is that everything "is a file"). Therefore things that would usually work on normal files won't work here.

Comment: Great question!  I never would have thought to even ask, and I can't imagine why you'd want to do this, but that's what makes it a great question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the files in `/proc` that youre saying are owned by `UID=1000` the the ones like `/proc/12345` (just number directories)? These are process accounting directories, the UID is set to that of the user running the program associated with that directory. If you launch a program with pid '12345' then `/proc/12345` will be owned by your user.

I doubt a chown on anything in proc will even work as `/proc` is not a real file system, its a pseudo-filesystem.

The same goes with `/dev`, the TTYs are owned by the user that is currently using them.

Comment: excellent info about `/proc`. I didn't realize these were process IDs. So that means it is pointless to change the `uid`.

Comment: `find -xdev` restricts itself to a single filesystem. You might need to run it once for each filesystem of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then changing the `UID`, numbered directories represent open handles to processes. You could either kill all the processes owned by `UID=1000` (using `ps`) or you can close all of its handles (using `lsof`).

Comment: killing all processes owned by a user is a lot simpler using `pkill -U`, instead of a manual `ps | grep` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither possible nor necessary to change the ownership of files under `/proc`. These files are not stored on a disk, they are generated by the kernel on the fly when you read them. The only ones that don't belong to root are files that provide information about a running process; these belong to the user who is running the process.

Before or after you've changed the ownership of the disk files, kill all the processes running as the former uid. (You can't (sensibly) change the uid of a running process.)

If there are terminals (`/dev/tty*` or `/dev/pts/*`) belonging to the user, you should change their uid. In all likelyhood there won't be many left after you kill the user's processes.