# How to fix GID of files in /proc?

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel

I'm not sure how it happened, but the group IDs of all files in my `/proc` directory (including non-process related files such as /proc/uptime) are set to 1001 instead of root. This was the ID of a spare user account that has now been deleted, and so the GID 1001 is now listed as UNKNOWN by the `stat` command.

I am unable to change them to root using either `chown` or `chgrp` (under `sudo`). Even after a reboot the GID's are still set to 1001.

Comment: Did you try killing all the user's processes?

Comment: Or have you tried rebooting?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28765/ .

Comment: ALL files in /proc are affected, not just the process subdirectories, and yes I have tried rebooting a couple of times and it didn't change anything.

Comment: There are no other files outside proc that belong to GID 1001 (or UID 1001), and no running processes with UID or GID 1001

Answer (score 3):

`/proc` is not a live filesystem, rather it's a pseudo filesystem that exposes data structures within the Linux kernel where you can either manipulate them or read them out using the CLI tools that feel more familiar when dealing with filesystems. For eg. `cat`, `echo`, etc.

Since you've changed this user's UID/GID these are likely processes that were running as this user, prior to you doing this change. I'd simply reboot the system and these should go away, since they're really only in `/proc` as active running processes on your system.

#### Example

Let's start with a user:

```
$ getent passwd user1
user1:x:1001:1001::/home/user1:/bin/bash
```

Now run our example process:

```
$ su -c "sleep 1000" user1 &
[1] 1677
```

Notice the process:

```
$ ps auxf | grep [s]leep
root      1676  0.0  0.2 195956  2424 pts/1    S    22:59   0:00                      \_ su -c sleep 1000 user1
user1     1677  0.0  0.0 107948   348 ?        Ss   22:59   0:00                      |   \_ sleep 1000
```

Now if we comment out the `user1` entry in our `/etc/passwd` file we get your identical scenario:

```
$ find /proc/1677 -ls | head
258536    0 dr-xr-xr-x   9 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 22:59 /proc/1677
272483    0 dr-xr-xr-x   3 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task
272527    0 dr-xr-xr-x   6 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677
272528    0 dr-x------   2 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fd
272570    0 lrwx------   1 1001     user1          64 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/1
272571    0 lrwx------   1 1001     user1          64 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/1
272572    0 lrwx------   1 1001     user1          64 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/1
272529    0 dr-x------   2 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo
272573    0 -r--------   1 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/0
272574    0 -r--------   1 1001     user1           0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/1
```

We cannot change these files, because they're not actual files, they're internal to the Linux kernel.

```
$ sudo chown user2 /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/1
```

Notice, no effect:

```
$ ll /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/1
-r-------- 1 1001 user1 0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/1
```

**NOTE:** The same issue applies to both the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files. I'm merely highlighting things above using the user & UID scenario, same goes for the group & GID.

Incidentally, if I uncomment my `user1` in `/etc/passwd` things go back to normal:

```
$ ll /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/1
-r-------- 1 user1 user1 0 Jul 16 23:01 /proc/1677/task/1677/fdinfo/1
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify; ALL files in /proc are affected, not just those in the process subdirectories. I did try rebooting once, and it didn't make any difference, but I will try again...

Comment: @Ben - no matter, you cannot run `chown` or `chgrp` commands in `/proc` and the procs under `/proc/#` are owned by whatever user's ran the processes.

Comment: Just tried rebooting, and its still the same.

Comment: Could it be a rootkit?

Comment: @Ben - possibly, what's the proc that's running with this unassigned UID/GID?

Comment: There is no running process and no other files on the system with that GID (I checked with `sudo ps -eo pid,egid,fgid,pgid,rgid,sgid,supgid,tgid,tid,tpgid,comm |grep 1001` and `sudo find / -path /proc -prune -o -gid 1001`)

Comment: @Ben - so it's completely gone then?

Comment: I meant there is no running process with GID 1001. The system seems to work fine, but my syslog files seem to have been altered.

Comment: @Ben - sounds very much like the system was compromised.